# How can I install MegaSync on Ubuntu 20.04? Software Center doesn't work

Tags: software-installation

My software installer does nothing in Ubuntu 20.04.

I downloaded a deb package and clicked on it, but nothing happened. I installed Chrome with the terminal by finding a command line that downloaded and installed the package through the terminal.

Now I want MegaSync and can't find a command line. If it allows me to download a package and it's a software installer, is it wrong to assume that it should open the package?

MegaSync offers the command line `sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb` but that comes back as invalid.

Is this going to be an issue for downloading anything on Ubuntu?

Comment: Open the software center, search for an application then click "Install" to install it.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center also does nothing when I click on it and the app I am looking for doesn't exist in GNOME, When I click on Ubuntu Software I get the exact same result as clicking on the package itself. The loading Icon and 15 seconds later nothing.

Comment: Hey Deaven Morris! Please paste the output of `snap list` in your question. You can edit your question by clicking on this link: [edit]. BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to install Mega Desktop App:

1. Go to https://mega.io/sync. Choose the Linux platform. Choose Ubuntu 20.04 as the Linux version.
2. Click on Download. A dialogue box might appear in Firefox depending upon the settings. Choose Save File and click OK.

   [image: Screenshot of dialogue box]
3. Open the folder where the file is saved. You can do that by clicking on the folder icon:

   [image: Screenshot of downloads in Firefox]
4. Once you are in the folder, right click and choose Open in Terminal.

   [image: Screenshot of righ-click options in Nautilus]
5. Now the terminal will open. Execute the following command:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install ./megasync-xUbuntu_20.04_amd64.deb
   ```

   **Note**: The file name may vary. Please use the name of the file which you have downloaded.

After following the above steps, the application would have  been successfully installed.